# Serving Static Pages ember.js

Tags: ember.js, routes, ember-data, handlebars.js

I'm currently retrofitting an old site and added ember. Previously when the user went products > product there was a link to a static page from there.

What's the best way to route to these static pages? (sellsheet in the object)

```
{
    id: 32,
    room: "String",
    subroom: "String",
    category: "String",
    image: "Content/Images/Products/img.PNG",
    name: "String",
    description: "String",
    bullets: [
        { content: "String" },
        { content: "String" },
        { content: "String" }
    ],
    sellsheet: "Content/Sellsheets/conveyor.html"
  }
```

Comment: No need for route are there? just use an regular `<a href=""></a>`

Comment: Well I could do that but I want the static pages to render in my template.

It's an old project where they developed a bunch of static pages and loaded them into an iframe inside the template. I was wondering if I had to make a route for each page or if there was a better way of doing it.

category > product index > product > links to sell sheet page associated with product

Comment: Compile static html files Handlebar templates and put them into view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this isn't the best way of doing it but it fit my needs.

I ended up just displaying the static page in an iframe at the bottom of the product page. Whenever you click view more, I hide the page with jQuery then show the iframe which gets the html loaded in through the anchor tag. Then I added a 'view less button' that hides the iframe and shows the page again.

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="product">
    <div id="valueprop-container">
      <div class="centered">
        <div class="col-left"><img {{bind-attr src=image}} /></div>
        <div class="col-right">
          <h2>{{{name}}}</h2>
          <p>{{{description}}}</p>
          <ul>
            {{#each bullets}}
            <li><span>{{{content}}}</span></li>
            {{/each}}
          </ul>
          {{#if sellsheet}}
            <a href="{{unbound sellsheet}}" target="frame" class="orange-button sell-sheet-click">View More</a>
          {{/if}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="shadow"></div>
    <div class="sellsheet">
      <button class="expand">View Less</button>
      <iframe name="frame" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen style="position: absolute; border: none;"></iframe>
    </div>
  </script>
```

**View**

```
App.ProductView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function(){
    var productPage = $('#valueprop-container');
    var sellSheet = $('.sellsheet');

    $('.sell-sheet-click').click('on', function(){
      productPage.hide();
      sellSheet.show();
    });

    $('.sellsheet').click('on', function(){
      productPage.show();
      sellSheet.hide();
    });
  }
});
```